# Implementing a zipwithindex predicate in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to implement a predicate of the form:

```
zipwithindex(?List1, ?List2)
```

which is true when the elements of `List2` are the same as in `List1` but are paired with the index of the element.

This is what I have:

```
zipwithindex([],I,S,S).
zipwithindex([H|T],I,S0,S):-
  append(S0,[H/I],S1),
  I1 is I+1,
  zipwithindex(T,I1,S1,S).
zipwithindex(List1,List2):-
  zipwithindex(List1,0,[],List2).
```

Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure:

```
zipwithindex(List1, List2) :-
   findall(E/I, nth0(I, List1, E), List2).
```

*Edit - after Tudor' comment*

bagof/3 it's much better than findall/3, as it doesn't introduce unwanted new variables. This can be of utmost importance when working with constrained variables - i.e. CLP(FD) or CHR

Comment: I would suggest `bagof/3` instead of `findall/3` in this case as, if there are unbound variables in `List1`, `List2` will have new variables instead of the original ones. E.g. `?- zipwithindex([X,Y,Z],L2).` will produce `L2 = [_G41/0, _G35/1, _G29/2].`